# xdvipdfmx:fatal: VF file ended prematurely

Tags: miktex, miktex-update, miktex2.9

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows10
Previously I had no such problem. But after updating the error message came out.
I googled but nobody had such problem before.
Could anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: somehow your font file has become corrupt, presumably the error message told you which font was corrupted? in which case you could presumably force the miktex package manager to re-install those fonts

Comment: Show a complete example that demonstrates the problem so the we can test and perhaps reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have removed the simpson package and reinstalled but no use. Where can I find those .vf files?

Comment: If you want help: Make a complete minimal example. The simpson package doesn't use vf fonts.